# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/Media'

Tags: reactjs

My MERN application is returning the error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/Media'`.

I am importing several react-bootstrap modules as shown:

```
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image"
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col"
import Media from "react-bootstrap/Media"
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row"
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button"
```

The remainder are working as expected. Any ideas why this one import wouldn't be found?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `Media` component exists inside `reactstrap` library, but you are using `react-bootstrap` which is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

Check your node_modules and see if it's there

Comment: I see now that it isn't. It also isn't on the react-bootstrap Github. Perhaps the tutorial I'm following is outdated?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue. I had to downgrade my version of react-bootstrap to import the Media component.

```
npm install react-bootstrap@1.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **Media** is changed to **Card** component in newer versions of react-bootstrap. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/

You should use:

```
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card"
```